# This is a Website using react which logins perfectly and works as expected on desktop [local] but gives error on mobile screen [local]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

App.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import BlogForm from "./components/BlogForm";
import UpdateUserForm from "./components/UpdateUserForm";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Blog from "./components/Blog";
import ResetPassword from "./components/ResetPassword";
import Profile from "./components/Profile";
import Feed from "./components/Feed";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Homepage from "./components/Homepage";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import NoResult from "./components/NoResult";
import ProtectedRoute from "./components/ProtectedRoute";
import auth from "./auth";
import { checkAuth } from "./helpers/helpers";
import PublicRoute from "./components/PublicRoute";

axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = localStorage.getItem("token");
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:5000";
export default function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(
    auth.isAuthenticated()
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (checkAuth) {
      auth.login(() => {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          {isAuthenticated ? <Homepage /> : <Login />}
        </Route>
        <PublicRoute exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <PublicRoute exact path='/register' component={Register} />
        <PublicRoute exact path='/reset-password' component={ResetPassword} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path='/home' component={Homepage} />
        <ProtectedRoute
          exact
          path='/create-blog'
          component={() => <BlogForm type='Create' />}
        />
        <ProtectedRoute
          exact
          path='/update-blog/:blogid'
          component={() => <BlogForm type='Update' />}
        />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
        <ProtectedRoute
          exact
          path='/my-feed'
          component={() => <Feed type='feed' />}
        />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path='/blog/:blogid' component={Blog} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path='/user/:userid' component={Profile} />
        <ProtectedRoute
          exact
          path='/search/:query'
          component={() => <Feed type='search' />}
        />
        <ProtectedRoute
          exact
          path='/update-user/:userid'
          component={UpdateUserForm}
        />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path='/no-results' component={NoResult} />
        <Route path='*' component={() => "404 NOT FOUND"} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Login.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import eyeIcon from "../images/eye.png";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import auth from "../auth";
import { checkAuth } from "../helpers/helpers";

export default function Login() {
  const history = useHistory();
  document.title = "Login";

  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [loginDetails, setLoginDetails] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setLoginDetails((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
  };

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login();
  };

  const login = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/auth/login", loginDetails);
      localStorage.setItem("token", res.data);
      if (checkAuth()) {
        auth.login(() => {
          history.push("/home");
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      const errors = err.response.data.errors;
      console.log(errors);
      errors.forEach((err) => {
        alert(err.msg);
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='login-register-container'>
      <div className='l-container d-flex justify-center align-center'>
        <h1>
          Login to <br />
          Your <br />
          Account <span>.</span>
        </h1>
        <form className='d-flex flex-col' onSubmit={handleLogin}>
          <input
            type='email'
            name='email'
            placeholder='Enter Your Email'
            value={loginDetails.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor='password'>
            <img
              className='toggle-password'
              src={eyeIcon}
              onClick={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}
              alt=''
            />
            <input
              type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
              name='password'
              placeholder='Enter Your Password'
              value={loginDetails.password}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <Link to='/reset-password'>Forgot Password</Link>
          <Link to='/register'>Not a User?</Link>
          <input type='submit' value='Login' />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This code works as expected on the desktop where I am building it on localhost but gives this error while running it on mobile browser [localhost].

It gives an err : Uncaught(in promise) TypeError : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data').

In desktop, if there is an error while logging in it produces an alert or else user is redirected to homepage.

In the backend to the post request of http://localhost:5000/auth/login returns a token if logged in perfectly or else returns errors array.

auth.js (Backend using Node.js/Express)

```
router.post(
  "/login",
  [
    check("email", "Enter a Valid Email Id").isEmail(),
    check("password", "Password is required").not().isEmpty(),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    // Errors array
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    // If the errors array is not empty set status 400:Bad request and give the error messages in json
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    // Get the details of the user
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
      let user = await db.query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email=$1", [email]);
      if (user.rows.length === 0) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ errors: [{ msg: "Invalid Credentials" }] });
      }

      let found;
      let newPassword = md5(password);

      if (user.rows[0].password === newPassword) {
        found = true;
      } else {
        found = false;
      }

      if (!found) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ errors: [{ msg: "Invalid Credentials" }] });
      }

      const payload = { userid: user.rows[0].userid };

      const accessToken = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_TOKEN, {
        expiresIn: "2h",
      });

      res.status(201).json(accessToken);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: the error implies that `res` at `res.data` or `err.response` at `err.response.data` is undefined ... which one is it?

Comment: My guess is you're opening the website on your mobile using your computer's IP address? React code is client-side, so hardcoding the backend URL to `localhost` will not work on other devices, because on your mobile, localhost is your mobile. You need to change that to the LAN IP, like `axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://192.168.1.X:5000";` Even better: always open the website using the LAN IP, then have your site use `location.hostname` to get the proper host

Comment: my guess is `err.response` is undefined - you should probably read how to [handle axios errors](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors) ... you'll see that `err.response` only exists if *The request was made and the server responded with a status code* - which ties in to what ChrisG has said - you probably got an error condition because *The request was made but no response was received* or *Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error*